# How to disable outbound internet connections on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm running a sensitive AWS Lambda function, which is required to never connect outbound to the Internet. However, lambda function uses several 3rd party open source libraries, which are not trust-able  (potentially leak data). Is there a way to block outbound connections entirely from Lambda?

Comment: You could use a VPC to run your lambda if you don't mind setting your own network configuration rules

Comment: You can create a VPC and create a secure EC2 instance and stop any incoming call from outside and any out going call from any lambda function inside this ec2. Also this function can be modified to be used by only selective lambda functions and will respond to only those.

Comment: @NAVIN an EC2 instance is not needed for that at all. Simply placing it in a VPC and configuring the security group correctly will block all outbound traffic.

Comment: @MarkB I'm new to AWS and that's how we achieved it. Thanks for telling me. Even I need to know different ways for this.

Answer (score 2):

If the code doesn't need outbound Internet access at all, place the function in a subnet in a VPC.

If the code needs outbound access but it can be limited to trusted servers, place the function in a private subnet having a route to a NAT Gateway, all in an Internet Gatway-enabled VPC. Then whitelist trusted server IPs in the security group associated with the Lambda.

[How a compromised NPM package can steal your secrets (POC + prevention)](https://www.maxivanov.io/how-compromised-npm-package-can-steal-your-secrets/).

Comment: Won't this have a huge impact on cold start times?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't configure the runtime environment in AWS Lambda, there's no way for you to disable outbound connections. Not through configuration, or via your code. You have two options:

1. Place the function inside a VPC, and deploy a NAT gateway. This is a bit cumbersome, will also affect performance, and your ability to easily work with AWS cloud services. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/ittus/aws-lambda-vpc-nat-examples
2. A better option would be to use a free security library called [FunctionShield](https://www.puresec.io/function-shield), which allows you to disable all outbound connections, except for AWS cloud services. It supports Node.js or Python at the moment (you didn't mention what runtime you're using). https://www.puresec.io/function-shield

Comment: It wouldn't need a NAT gateway since the goal is to block outbound Internet access. A NAT is only needed if you want to provide outbound Internet access.

Comment: Function shield is no longer being supported & not recommended for production